# Groupby and contatinate strings with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

UPD: the error is due to having NaNs in the 'Neighborhood' column. Is there any solution to ignore them?

I have a dataset with 3 columns: Postcode, Borough, Neighborhood. More than one neighborhood can exist in one postal code area. These rows need to be combined into one row with the neighborhoods separated with a comma.

What I've tried is:

```
df.groupby(['Postcode', 'Borough'])['Neighborhood'].apply(lambda neighborhood: ','.join(neighborhood))
```

or

```
 df.groupby(['Postcode', 'Borough'])['Neighborhood'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Every time i get this error: *"TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found"*

```
df.groupby(['Postcode', 'Borough'])['Neighborhood'].apply(lambda group_series: group_series.tolist()).reset_index()
```

Adds a list as row values, which is close, but not exactly what I need. Please help? (data types below fyi)..

```
df.dtypes

Postcode        object
Borough         object
Neighborhood    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Do you have `nan` in your columns Neighborhood?

Comment: We'd need to see your data to understand why it fails _on your data_.

Comment: Indeed, this happens due to NaNs in column Neighborhood. Is there any way to ignore them and concatenate only existing data?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`df.dropna(subset=['Neighborhood']).groupby(['Postcode', 'Borough'])['Neighborhood'].apply(','.join)`

This will drop NaN values in the neighborhood column prior to performing the groupby operation.